# Pure CSS way of determining whether a child element is clipped by a parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a child element and a parent element.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" />
</div>
```

The child may be positioned outside of the parent or may be partially clipped by the parent.  When this happens, I want to set it to display: none.

Is there a pure css way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I don't think its possible

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Browsers are designed to show the content come hell or high water, the content must be rendered!  This is the holy grail of CSS!

Comment: @Marc - there are plenty of reasons to hide content.  That's why we have a display: none property.

Comment: Just curious to know why partially clipped content should be hidden...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform that kind of test with css, it is not possible.